# Mergesort in Python 3.4.3 not working; typeerror for NoneType

Tags: python, mergesort

I'm currently trying a code for sorting and merging lists but I can't get it to work:

```
def mergesort(L):
    """Returns a new sorted list with the same elements as L"""
    print (L)
    if len(L) < 2:
        return L[:]
    else:
        middle = int(len(L) / 2)
        left = mergesort(L[:middle])
        right = mergesort(L[middle:])
        together = merge(left,right)
        print( 'merged', together)
        return
```

This is what happens:

```
>>> test = [1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 7, 20, 9]
>>> mergesort(test)
[1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 7, 20, 9]
[1, 3, 5, 6]
[1, 3]
[1]
[3]
merged [1, 3]
[5, 6]
[5]
[6]
merged [5, 6]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#347>", line 1, in <module>
    mergesort(test)
  File "C:/Python27/python omg 2 samma/lec10.py", line 30, in mergesort
    left = mergesort(L[:middle])
  File "C:/Python27/python omg 2 samma/lec10.py", line 32, in mergesort
    together = merge(left,right)
  File "C:/Python27/python omg 2 samma/lec10.py", line 7, in merge
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

It seems that somehow the variables left and right are not properly saved since if I instead write this I get better results although it still ends up with an error (changed how I write "together"):

```
def mergesort(L):
    """Returns a new sorted list with the same elements as L"""
    print (L)
    if len(L) < 2:
        return L[:]
    else:
        middle = int(len(L) / 2)
        left = mergesort(L[:middle])
        right = mergesort(L[middle:])
        together = merge(mergesort(L[:middle]),mergesort(L[middle:]))
        print( 'merged', together)
        return
```

I get:

```
>>> test = [1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 7, 20, 9]
>>> mergesort(test)
[1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 7, 20, 9]
[1, 3, 5, 6]
[1, 3]
[1]
[3]
[1]
[3]
merged
[1, 3]
[5, 6]
[5]
[6]
[5]
[6]
merged [5, 6]
[1, 3]
[1]
[3]
[1]
[3]
merged [1, 3]
[5, 6]
[5]
[6]
[5]
[6]
merged [5, 6]
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<pyshell#349>", line 1, in <module>
     mergesort(test)
   File "C:/Python27/python omg 2 samma/lec10.py", line 30, in mergesort
     left = mergesort(L[:middle])
   File "C:/Python27/python omg 2 samma/lec10.py", line 32, in mergesort
     together = merge(mergesort(L[:middle]),mergesort(L[middle:]))
   File "C:/Python27/python omg 2 samma/lec10.py", line 7, in merge
     while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `mergesort()` returns `None`, unless the length of `L` is shorter than 2. You need to return `together` as well:

```
def mergesort(L):
    """Returns a new sorted list with the same elements as L"""
    print (L)
    if len(L) < 2:
        return L[:]
    else:
        middle = int(len(L) / 2)
        left = mergesort(L[:middle])
        right = mergesort(L[middle:])
        together = merge(left,right)
        print( 'merged', together)
        return together
```

If you don't, either `left` or `right` ends up being set to `None` if `L[:middle]` is longer than 1, and your `merge()` call fails.

This fixed version then produces:

```
>>> mergesort(test)
[1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 7, 20, 9]
[1, 3, 5, 6]
[1, 3]
[1]
[3]
merged [1, 3]
[5, 6]
[5]
[6]
merged [5, 6]
merged [1, 3, 5, 6]
[4, 7, 20, 9]
[4, 7]
[4]
[7]
merged [4, 7]
[20, 9]
[20]
[9]
merged [9, 20]
merged [4, 7, 9, 20]
merged [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 20]
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 20]
```